# .htaccess URL Rewrite Problem (Scripts don't load)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am having a problem with an URL rewrite issue in .htaccess.

**Here is my rewrite code** :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule     ^terms(.*)  terms.php [L,nc]
RewriteRule ^formgate\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{64,64})$ formgate.php?g=$1 [L,nc]
```

When the page loads it functions properly except that all of my stylesheets, javascript files, etc do not load properly. If you check the errors it states 404 not found and that $ is not defined. Thanks

Comment: What is the URL/path of your CSS and JS files?

Comment: Please show some example URLs to style sheets and Javascript files, and what error you get when trying to access them directly.

Comment: The best answer i got for this problem , you can find it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689363/how-to-fix-resource-file-path-after-using-htaccess

Answer (score 4):

This problem often comes from using **relative URL's** to stylesheets or javascript files and combining it with a virtual directory structure. If you have a rewrite like this:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ articles.php
```

Then you have a URL like:

```
http://example.com/articles/2011/03/14/title-of-the-article
```

which contains the HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/general.css" />
```

no matter if your file `artices.php` resides in the root of your web directory the browser  knows nothing about it as the matters of `mod_rewrite` are hidden from the browser. So it will ask for the file:

```
http://example.com/articles/2011/03/14/title-of-the-article/css/general.css
```

which obviously does not exist. So I recommend specifying URL's relative to your web root. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/general.css" />
```

Mind the `/` in front of theURL.

Please note the following: when your URL starts with a `/` character it means a path relative to the *root of the webpage*. Check out this example directurey structure:

```
/
    /index.html
    /afolder
        /afolder/stylesheets
            /afolder/stylesheets/first.css
            /afolder/stylesheets/second.css
        /afolder/images
            /afolder/images/a.jpg
    /otherfolder
        /otherfolder/something.html
```

Comment: I make / in front of the URL,but it does not work. If i make ./ in front of the URL,it work but another page is not work ... Help me ... P/s : I'm newbie in English :D

Comment: @TrungMR I added some note and example to the answer. Check it out better to understand relative path. (Not relative to the html page but relative to the *web root* folder.)