# How to fix resource file path after using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

When browser displays:

http://example.com/first/second

and encounters a relative URL such as:

```
<img src="site/images/photo.png">
```

It translates the relative URL to (respectively):

http://example.com/first/second/site/images/photo.png

so what's the solution

Comment: A lot of context missing here, but, isn't your regex looking for '.php' in the path??

Comment: Yes every thing works good but the main problem when i include php file that contain mapping on javascript and css files they gives me file not found

Comment: Use it this way: `script src="/js/jsfile.js"`

Comment: i tired this solution but the main problem they redirect me to root directory to htdocs file not to my project file.

Comment: You can turn rewrite logging up, it should help you troubleshoot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess URL Rewrite Problem (Scripts don't load)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130138/htaccess-url-rewrite-problem-scripts-dont-load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the code to just below the `RewriteEngine On` line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

You can also added the following to the `<head>`, which might work either.

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

Comment: Ok this solution sounds good for me but the problem i need to use relative path not the absolute one

Comment: The above wouldn't create absolute links. The `<base>` tag defines the  base of the link and the `src/href/etc` would be kept the same.