# PHP SEO friendly with clean URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, friendly-url

Currently I works on to transfer my site into SEO friendly URL (in localhost),

Here's the original URL with query string:

```
http://{ip}/sitename/item.php?category=44
```

I want convert to:

```
http://{ip}/sitename/item/category/44
```

**.htaccess** file (same directory with item.php):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes

<files page>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^.*$ item.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
    RewriteRule ^/item/([0-9]+) /item.php?category=$1
</IfModule>

<Files *htaccess>
Deny from all
</Files>
```

in `item.php`, I use `$_GET['category']`

```
$category = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['category']));

$list = $listing->get_items($category, $mysqli);

if($list == 0){
echo '<p><h2>Page not found</h2></p>';
die();
}
```

**Problem 1:**
When I loaded `http://{ip}/sitename/item/category/44`, the page cannot get the variable passes to `get_item()`, the page is shown `Page not found`? 44 is suppose return a value.

**Problem 2:**
My page doesn't loaded referrer files, all `*.css` `*.js` etc are just ignore?

Comment: Where your rewrite base definition? I am sure you are missing the correct location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM 2 - The problem has arised as you have not mentioned the base path.

You need to assign base path to load css and other references.

Try using this in `<head>` tag `<base href="http://www.MYSITE.com/" />`

This will load your css/js.

Comment: I use @Neeraj Kumar script and added `<base href="http://www.MYSITE.com/" />`, now page is working well. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule item/category/(.*) item.php?category=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: No rewriting has happened here – (you only think it has, beause your script `item.php` got called anyway, because you had `item` in the URL and MultiViews has done its work) – paths the RewriteRules match on in .htaccess *never* start with a `/`, so remove it.

Problem 2: Has been discussed many times before (and should also be obvious to anyone who knows the basics of how completion of relative URLs works) – see f.e. [.htaccess URL Rewrite Problem (Scripts don't load)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130138/htaccess-url-rewrite-problem-scripts-dont-load)

Answer (score 0):

> RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteBase /sitename
>   RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+)/?$ item.php?category=$1 [L,NC]